# Can't make the input on my calculator evaluate the sum

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning to code and am currently building my first calculator using javascript. It works coming down to the input being projected on the screen from clicking the button and the 'C' clear button clears the input screen, however I keep getting a syntax error when using the '=" button when trying to evaluate and need assistance, have tried multiple ways but am struggling when trying to use the screen.value.

```js
// Selecting elements

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let screen = document.getElementById("input");

//function to add input onto screen
const addTo = function(e) {
  screen.value += e;
};

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // log click to a variable
    const input = buttons[i].value;

    // add clicked input to screen
    addTo(input);

    // make screeninput evaluate sum
    if (input === "=") {
      let equals = eval(screen.value);
      equals = screen.value;
    } else if (input === "C") {
      screen.value = " ";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>MY CALCULATOR</h1>
<div id=c alc class="calc-container">
  <div id=s creen class="input-container">
    <input type=text name=d isplay id=i nput class="user-input" value="" />
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper" class="button-container">

    <input value="9" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="8" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="7" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="6" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="5" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="4" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="3" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="2" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="1" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="*" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="0" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="+" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="/" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="-" type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="=" type=b utton class="btn equals">
    <input value="." type=b utton class="btn" />
    <input value="C" type=b utton class="btn" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Building your first calculator is a great project! To help with answering this question, could you copy and paste the syntax error message you're getting? It should refer to a specific line and can be really helpful for narrowing done where the problem is

Comment: Ah I should have! Sorry this is my first question and definitely won't be my last. My problem was solved. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of `=` you are trying to evaluate an expression with `=`, for example `10+2=`. Which is an invalid expression. You should avoid that `=` from the eval statement and execute only `10+2`.

Call `addTo` only if the input is not `=` and `C` to fix this.

```js
// Selecting elements

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let screen = document.getElementById("input");

//function to add input onto screen
const addTo = function (e) {
  screen.value += e;
};

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    // log click to a variable
    const input = buttons[i].value;


    // make screeninput evaluate sum
    if (input === "=") {
      let equals = eval(screen.value);
      screen.value = equals;
    } else if (input === "C") {
      screen.value = " ";
    } else {
      // add clicked input to screen
      addTo(input);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>MY CALCULATOR</h1>
<div id=calc class="calc-container">
  <div id=screen class="input-container">
    <input type=text name=display id=input class="user-input" value="">
    </input>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper" class="button-container">

    <input value="9" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="8" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="7" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="6" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="5" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="4" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="3" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="2" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="1" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="*" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="0" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="+" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="/" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="-" type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="=" type=button class="btn equals"></input>
    <input value="." type=button class="btn"></input>
    <input value="C" type=button class="btn"></input>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies I thought you could approve more than one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you do `eval(screen.value)`.

When you call the `eval` function, your `screen.value` is `'xxxx='`.

This is not in the syntax of `eval`.

Comment: I suggest reading this- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!. Eval() should actually be avoided. For a personal project, especially one of your first ones, it is not something to be worried about. It is never a bad idea to learn though!